# facebook messenger dots instead of titles in web_urls and postbacks

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

For some reason all titles in web_urls and postbacks were replaced by dots as on the picture.

There is no error message on the console. The buttons are clickable.

[image]

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Facing the same issue! 
Yesterday, they released a new (but probably buggy) api version.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog

Comment: Keep calm! your code is ok! 
Every bot on the messenger is affected by their new api release. It's their api bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not an issue anymore.**

They've fixed it :)

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1087423794766431/?disable_redirect=0